# MySql combine records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to make some agreggation on my table. For instance i have to find records where CreateDate = some date and for all that records to combine them. For example:

```
ID   Name   Kpi1  Kpi2  Kpi3  CreateDate
1    GHX    45    NULL  NULL  2017-02-09
2    GHX    NULL  66    3o    2017-02-09
3    TRE    NULL  44    33    2017-02-09
4    TRE    89    NULL  NULL  2017-02-09
```

There will be always two records per specific name. One record will have filled out columns which second not and vice versa.

Therefore at the end in my table i should get that result instead of having 4 records. So means replace somehow those data - i do not know delete and insert again or whatever.

Note that ID is PK/AI, rest are strings and CreateDate is DateTime

```
ID   Name   Kpi1  Kpi2  Kpi3  CreateDate
1    GHX    45    66    30    2017-02-09
3    TRE    89    44    33    2017-02-09
```

Is that possible? I would like to have a query to be able to pass specific date for one or date range for all records from specific dates to be combined.

Comment: I think you are coming at this from the wrong direction and should be selecting where data = something or date between something and something else grouping by name.

Comment: it could be yes i want just to have possibility to aggregate just for particural date or by all or range

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the result you want but im not sure why you would want that

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE(MIN(ID), Name, MIN(Kpi1), MIN(Kpi2), MIN(Kpi3), 
 MIN(CreateDate))
 SELECT MIN(ID), Name, MIN(Kpi1), MIN(Kpi2), MIN(Kpi3), MIN(CreateDate)
 FROM Table1
 WHERE CreateDate = '2017-02-09'
 GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: @P.Salmon i have added it in there but i dont know why you would need it as the dates are all the same

Comment: because the op would like to have a query to be able to pass specific date for one or date range for all records from specific dates to be combined and the data provided in the question is only sample data.

Comment: yes, as Salmon said in table there will more data from diffrent dates. However not that your query doesn't replace existing data into what i want. It is just select

Comment: @Unknown well it would be helpful to see the table data then if you want something else. My answer will give you the result you wanted from your post result example

Comment: it's just a select we need something like replacment or delete/insert. It's just simple table: ID is PK/AI rest are strings and CreateDate is DateTime

Comment: what about oryginall rows and insert statment, could you update your answer please.

Comment: Im sorry i dont really know what you're looking for. My answer would give you a result set you have demonstrated. For anything else i would need you to update your question

Comment: in the example table containing 4 records and those records should be replaced (in table of course) by 2 records (in example as well) based on the condition i described.

Comment: So you're trying to insert those values into a table? why not just query it or delete the data you dont want

Comment: exactly i want to delete 4 them and insert two of them (based on that example)

Comment: @Unknown just insert that select statement

Comment: i think what we still missing is delete .. can you update so i mark as answer

Comment: and why do you group by?

Comment: If you dont group by and you just delete you will not get the result you want. Grouping will put those columns together and give you the result you want. Otherwise if you delete a row you're going to keep those null values

Comment: @Unknown trust me, if you try that query you will get the result you want. If its been help and upvote and answer tick would be appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: but the oryginal 4 rows will be replaced by new two without delete statment and why you used MIN instead of MAX ?

Comment: @Unknown you can use either. It wont matter because you're comparing an integer with a null value. You're looking for a group by statement rather than a delete to solve your particular question

Comment: so does it mean that your query will do the job?

Comment: @Unknown yes, my query will give you the result you're looking for providing you put in the correct table names that you have. The select statement will do the job but if you want to insert it just add the insert statement as well

Comment: @Unknown did this help?

Comment: i will check over week and give the mark. Again what i need is to replace records by other records according to example 4 records should be deleted from table and two records should be inserted. If your answer do the job i will mark it as answer soon.

Comment: ok let me know how it goes. If you need more help let me know and i will try and understand your question better if it is wrong

Comment: Hi again, i checked your query however i get error: duplicate key entry '2350' for PRIMARY. Besides in your insert perhaps MIN keyword are wrong because my mysql not allow for that so i delete them from insert.

Comment: No it will have nothing to do with MIN. That error is because you're trying to insert into a table that already has records with the same primary key. Try inserting into a new table or change your primary key to auto increment